# ...putting us and the rest of the world on so

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'on so' mean and how it changes the meaning of the phrase?

> Yes, I was going to ask Mr. Quinn why he insists on putting us and the
>   rest of the world **on so**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky because it combines a two-word verb (verb plus preposition) that is a separable two-word verb with an idiomatic usage of the word so. Separable two-word verbs can take direct objects and here, the direct object is a compound direct object: there are two of them.

The verb is: to put on, and it can take direct objects in typical usage such as:

Don't put me on.

Don't put us on.

You're putting us on, aren't you?

**So** is used to mean: **so much** or to a great extent and it placed after a verb in certain cases:

- They do go on so. = They do go on so much. go on=to make a fuss, to whine about something.
- She always is complaining so [so much] about her job.
- He never used to whine so. [so much or to that extent]

The parse is therefore:

he insists on|| putting us and the rest of the world on|| so

The difficulty, therefore, is three-fold. There is to **insist on** (correct preposition for the verb insist), to **put [someone] on** with a **double direct object** (us and the rest of the world) and the **so** standing for **so much**.

who said English structure was easy?:)

Answer (score 1):

Parse this as *putting on* with *so*="in this manner" or "to this degree" as a modifier.

*Put on* here is extended from the metaphor of "donning" a disguise or false identity to mean "deceive" or "trick". *You're putting me on* means "You're kidding me, you're trying to trick me."

> I was going to ask Mr. Quinn why he insists on deceiving us this way.

Note that the following line is

> Some might be persuaded to doubt his sincerity